# How do I find the sum of all values from two different arrays in Perl?

Tags: perl, arrays, sum

How to find the sum of all values from two different arrays in Perl?

```
@array1 = (1, 2, 3);
@array2 = (10, 10, 10);
```

`@sumofarray1and2 = ?`

So I figured I can do two kinds of things here. I can do two `foreach` loops and add contents of `@array1` and `@array2` first then get the sum of both.

Comment: do you mean 36 or (11, 12, 13) ?

Comment: @Eric, I wasn't sure so its for both. I figured out the 36 part. Can you explain the second part?

Comment: => I've updated my answer with a description of how it works

Answer (score 9):

```
my $sum = 0;
$sum += $_ for (@array1, @array2);
```

Comment: Modules are cool and everything, but it chafes me to see people recommend a module for something that could be done in two lines of conventional Perl. And if you are leaning the language or otherwise asking a simple question, figuring out how to do the job without modules is usually a more valuable experience.

Comment: And some people call Perl a write-only language.

Answer (score 3):

Since the sum of both lists is already here, this is how to sum the lists element wise:

```
my @sums = map {$array1[$_] + $array2[$_]} 0 .. $#array1;
```

This assumes the lists are the same length.

This code uses the `map` function which applies its block to a list, and generates a new list from the block's return value. The block shown will add elements from each array at index `$_`.  `$_` is set by `map` to the values of its passed in list.  `$#array1` is the index of the last element, in this case 2.  That makes the list passed into map `(0, 1, 2)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
use List::Util qw(sum);
@array1=(1,2,3);
@array2=(10,10,10);
print sum(@array1, @array2);
```

Answer (score 1):

For the summing, use [List::Util](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::Util). For the "two arrays", just put them in a list and you'll get a list of all their values.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util;

my @foo = (1,2,3);
my @bar = (4,5,6);

print List::Util::sum(@foo, @bar), "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is with the [fold](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Fold) family, *e.g.*, [`reduce`](http://search.cpan.org/~gbarr/Scalar-List-Utils-1.23/lib/List/Util.pm#reduce):

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -l

use List::Util qw/ reduce /;

@array1 = (1, 2, 3);
@array2 = (10, 10, 10);

print reduce { $a + $b } @array1, @array2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util qw( sum );
use List::MoreUtils qw( pairwise );

our ($a, $b);
my @array1 = (1, 2, 3);
my @array2 = (10, 10, 10);

my @sum = pairwise { $a + $b } @array1, @array2;

printf "%s : %d\n", "@sum", sum @sum;
```

Output:

```
C:\Temp> s
11 12 13 : 36
```